# sshfs mapped folder changes group ownership from apache to wheel

Tags: phpstorm, rhel, sshfs

**Problem:**

When I save a php file to a development server over [sshfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS), the group is changed from *apache* to *[wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_%28Unix_term%29)*. Given that the file belongs to my user and is readable by apache, this breaks the dev copy. I have to reset the group after every save.

**Server file permissions**:

As [recommended by the Drupal community](https://www.drupal.org/node/244924), my user owns the files but they are grouped to *apache*.

**How I'm mapped:**

I have a script that helps me do a local map to development servers running RHEL 7.1, change the folder in term, open a file browser, and start PHP Storm. I've set up the following convenience function for myself to do all this in one nice command.

`$ sshmap devsvr`

Which executes this function:

```
function sshmap {

  if [[ -z $2 ]]; then
    basefolder="/var/www/html/"
  else
    basefolder=$2
  fi

  fusermount -uz ~/mount/$1
  mkdir -p ~/mount/$1
  sshfs me@$1.domain.ext:$basefolder ~/mount/$1


  # file browser
  nemo  ~/mount/$1 &

  # change local folder to that mount point
  cd ~/mount/$1

  # start phpstorm
  pstorm $HOME/mount/$1 2>/dev/null &
}
```

**Question:**

How can I control this and prevent this change? Is there an argument in `sshfs` that I'm missing?

**Errata:**
Safe write is turned on in PHPSTorm

[image]

Comment: Please check if turning Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Use "safe write" (save changes to temporary file first) option off helps

Comment: It appears to already be turned on. I've included a screenshot in the main question.

Comment: it's enabled by default. Please try turning it off per my suggestion.

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood.